# Want to access literal value into javascript

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, asp.net-4.0, literals

I have got a literal control on page (with some data on it). i want to access it in javascript and want to put some text on it. please tell me how can i access literal control in JavaScript. I was trying with following code-

```
<asp:Literal  ID="lblPerInstanceListing" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

Javascript:

```
 var value= document.getElementById('<%=lblPerInstanceListing.ClientID %>')
```

I am getting null value return by this.

Comment: An asp literal control doens't emit a tag in the html (you can verify with view-source in your browser) so there is no way the DOM has an id. You can use asp:Label (that generates a span tag) which is part of the DOM. Another option is to use an parent element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An ASP.NET Literal control does not by itself insert any HTML into a webpage.  Your Literal control is a placeholder for text or HTML you will set in your code behind.

You should wrap your literal in a DIV or SPAN and give that an ID and reference that DIV or SPAN in the JavaScript

WebForm:

```
<span id="yourId"><asp:Literal  ID="lblPerInstanceListing" runat="server"></asp:Literal></span>
```

JavaScript:
**Solved by this code.**

```
var value= document.getElementById('yourId').innerText;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<span id="yourId" runat="server"></span>
```

js :

```
var value= document.getElementById('yourId').innerHTML;
```

It is not better then use this code??
You can put in span enableviewstate to false if You need.

Answer (score -2):

It's a `Literal`. It renders literal HTML to the page. It doesn't render any container matching the `ClientID` that you can access on the client side.

Either put a `div` or `span` *in* the literal with an ID you can use, or use e.g. a `Label` or `Panel` control that does render a wrapping `span` or `div` you can use.